# How to use express.response.redirect while setting a customer response body?

Tags: node.js, express, redirect

When redirecting in express, it is possible to set a response status and the redirect URL, like so:

```js
    res.redirect(302, redirectUrl);
```

When you `curl` this, it does not have a response body.
Only headers (including `Location`) and status code.

```sh
curl -X GET http://localhost:3000/my-redirect
Found. Redirecting to https://example.com/foo
```

Questions:

(1) Is it possible to set a response body as well?
If so, how?

(2) Is there a standard that recommends against doing this?
If so, links please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With express **`it's not possible`** as you can see the code here https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L909-L953 it expects 1 or 2 parameters and it also ends the response so after response end you can't send any response but as always you can built custom or override it.

Also for 302 redirects message body **`isn't required`** but you can send it as you can see in express code express does sends it to browser **`unless it's a HEAD request`**.

Links: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302, https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4.3